# Enhanced For-Loop raises a compilation error with Custom Collection implementing Iterable interface

Tags: java, collections, iterator, iterable

I'm trying to make a recursive list data structure in Java, similar to lists in functional languages.

I want it to implement `Iterable` so that it can be used in `for`-each loops.

So I'me implemented the `iterator()` method which creates an `Iterator`, and this loop works fine (`list` is of type `RecursiveList<Integer>`):

```
for (Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer i = it.next();
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Now I was under the impression that `for (int i : list)` is basically just a syntactic sugar over the `for`-loop above, but when I try to use the `for`-each, I'm getting a compilation error:

```
incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why it isn't working. Here's the relevant code:

```
import java.util.*;

class RecursiveList<T> implements Iterable {

  private T head;
  private RecursiveList<T> tail;
  // head and tail are null if and only if the list is empty
  // [] = { head = null; tail = null}
  // [1,2] = { head = 1; tail = { head = 2; tail = { head = null; tail = null } } }

  public RecursiveList() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
  }

  private RecursiveList(T head, RecursiveList<T> tail) {
    this.head = head;
    this.tail = tail;
  }

  public boolean add(T newHead) {
    RecursiveList<T> tail = new RecursiveList<T>(this.head, this.tail);
    this.head = newHead;
    this.tail = tail;
    return true;
  }

  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    RecursiveList<T> init = this;

    return new Iterator<T>() {
      private RecursiveList<T> list = init;

      public boolean hasNext() {
          return list.head != null;
      }

      public T next() {
          T ret = list.head;
          if (ret == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
          list = list.tail;
          return ret;
      }
    }
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RecursiveList<Integer> list = new RecursiveList<Integer>();

    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);

    // works:
    for(Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
      Integer i = it.next();
      System.out.println(i);
    }
    // output:
    // 3
    // 2
    // 1

    // doesn't work:
    // for (int i : list) System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

What's making me feel real stupid is my IDE is catching the problem too and underlining `list` giving the same error message, so there must be something obviously wrong with how I've written the types that I'm missing, I just can't figure what's happening since `iterator()` seems to be successfully creating an `Iterator` instance with the right type based on the more verbose loop working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interface [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html) is generic, but your custom Collection implements iterable of row type, which is effectively `Iterable<Object>`. For that reason, elements retrieved from your collection inside the enhanced `for`-loop are treated as being of type `Object`.

You need to change the declaration of your Collection to:

```
class RecursiveList<T> implements Iterable<T>
```